# Disable window docking when desktop corners are touched (AeroSnap)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm making a Flat Movable Window in WPF, and I disabled autoresising when a user drag and drops the window in a desktop corner:

```
        MaxWidth = MinWidth = Width = ComponentModelItems.Width;
        MaxHeight = MinHeight = Height = ComponentModelItems.Heigth;
```

The problem is that the location of the window is still docking to the corners and I don't want this to happen. How can I make my Window not to make a Fusion with the desktop corners?

Please suggest a way. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean this option: "prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen"

Comment: @Sag1v Kind of. I already found it. It's called AeroSnap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found this solution. Too easy lol

```
        ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

This will disable AeroSnap in the Window.